# How to fix ibtool failed with Main.storyboard error: shouldBeArchived unrecognized

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, build, ibtool

I have never encountered this problem before. The application used to run perfectly but now it always says this error. I have tried cleaning and rebooting. I have tried resetting IOS Simulator. I have tried deleting derived data.

This is what xcode build it says:

```
CompileStoryboard AITEST/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
cd /Users/tinkl/Documents/project-xcode/testProject/AITEST
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:(null)/Users/tinkl/.gem/ruby/2.0.0(null):(null)/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0(null):(null)/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0(null):/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --target-device iphone --errors --warnings --notices --module AITEST --minimum-deployment-target 8.1 --output-partial-info-plist /Users/tinkl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AITEST-eyqkoubdyxykegdhwecchlxhuetf/Build/Intermediates/AITEST.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AITEST.build/Main-SBPartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/tinkl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AITEST-eyqkoubdyxykegdhwecchlxhuetf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AITEST.app/Base.lproj/Main.storyboardc /Users/tinkl/Documents/project-xcode/testProject/AITEST/AITEST/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard

2015-06-16 10:44:10.053 ibtoold[20616:447845] -[IBUIViewControllerAutolayoutGuide shouldBeArchived]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdd8d4b0d40
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
/Users/tinkl/Documents/project-xcode/testProject/AITEST/AITEST/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: Exception while running ibtool: -[IBUIViewControllerAutolayoutGuide shouldBeArchived]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdd8d4b0d40
```

run system:

1 : OS X EL Capitan version, 10.11

2 : XCode Version 6.1 (6A1052c)

3 : command tools version 6.1

Any help for this would be great. I also have quite a large storyboard. Does that matter?

Thanks in advance!

> Other Reault:
>
> 1. if checked stroyboard's UIViewController's autoLayout to off, will build Success.
> 2. if use UITableViewController in storyboard use autolayout to on, will build Success.

here ibtool version:

tinkl:~ tinkl$ ibtool --version

> bundle-version 1878
>   short-bundle-version 6.1

Comment: [IBUIViewControllerAutolayoutGuide shouldBeArchived]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdd8d4b0d40
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */

Comment: using a newer version of xcode worked for me. the downside? can't use an older simulator.

Answer (score 6):

This issue was resolved for me after updating my Xcode version.

I ran into this issue after working on a project on in an older version of Xcode and upgrading to El Capitan without then upgrading Xcode.

After upgrading Xcode again, it worked.

Comment: It would be nice if you included what revision of Xcode you updated to.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get this to work either but what I did was symlink to a newer version of Xcode. I linked `6.3.2` to `6.2.0`. I am not sure of the implications of doing this.

`ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool /Applications/Xcode_6.2.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool`

Comment: So, you could not solve the problem but you did something else. And you're not sure of the implications. Is this an answer?

Comment: Its better then nothing... It fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Great trick - too scared of the implications to use this in prod, but great for getting old projects to run in a quick n' dirty fashion.

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually occurs when you copy any UI from storyboard to XIB or vice-versa. Once you copy any thing cross check if the things are supported in XIB, like if I copy anything from storyboard to xib file, then there are many thing which are not supported (obviously because storyboard is a newer version of xib) and simple example for this is tableview prototype cell.

So just remove those unsupported things from UI and thats it. It will start working again.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused due to un-matching of size of storyBoard designed by you and of simulator. This can be solved in two ways, by changing size of storyBoard or by de-selecting autolayout option. Autolayout is to place tools as it as in every resolutions.
So when mismatching occurs. supposed to be trimmed to fit in screensize. That is the reason behind this error.