# Error while compiling xcode. ibtools could not find class named UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

I got this error message in Xcode while compiling a project which was passed down to me:

```
CompileStoryboard proj1/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
    cd /Users/user1/Documents/Projects/MyProject/iOS/MyProject_iOS
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --module proj1 --output-partial-info-plist /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/proj1-aevyxfxutfenlmbqvkeyzpywwekg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/proj1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/proj1.build/Main-SBPartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --target-device iphone --minimum-deployment-target 8 --output-format human-readable-text --compilation-directory /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/proj1-aevyxfxutfenlmbqvkeyzpywwekg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/proj1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/proj1.build/Base.lproj /Users/user1/Documents/Projects/MyProject/iOS/MyProject_iOS/proj1/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
2017-11-16 17:12:26.655 ibtoold[20474:699803] *** Assertion failure in -[IBBinaryUnarchiver classForClassName:], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-13529/Foundation/Utilities/IBBinaryUnarchiver.m:316
/* com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings */
/Users/user1/Documents/Projects/MyProject/iOS/MyProject_iOS/proj1/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:TiJ-pH-k9k: warning: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width before iOS 8.0
/Users/user1/Documents/Projects/MyProject/iOS/MyProject_iOS/proj1/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:iOT-6X-DYN: warning: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width before iOS 8.0
/Users/user1/Documents/Projects/MyProject/iOS/MyProject_iOS/proj1/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:U3p-FK-Uaj: warning: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width before iOS 8.0
/Users/user1/Documents/Projects/MyProject/iOS/MyProject_iOS/proj1/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:HrH-hF-d04: warning: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width before iOS 8.0
/Users/user1/Documents/Projects/MyProject/iOS/MyProject_iOS/proj1/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:g6v-21-vpr: warning: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width before iOS 8.0
/Users/user1/Documents/Projects/MyProject/iOS/MyProject_iOS/proj1/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:FyA-39-0eM: warning: Prototype collection view cells must have reuse identifiers
/Users/user1/Documents/Projects/MyProject/iOS/MyProject_iOS/proj1/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:hHE-SH-oro: warning: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width before iOS 8.0
/Users/user1/Documents/Projects/MyProject/iOS/MyProject_iOS/proj1/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:mf7-kd-Iuk: warning: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width before iOS 8.0
/Users/user1/Documents/Projects/MyProject/iOS/MyProject_iOS/proj1/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:3lL-wL-gSf: warning: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width before iOS 8.0
/Users/user1/Documents/Projects/MyProject/iOS/MyProject_iOS/proj1/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:sdL-YA-l1j: warning: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width before iOS 8.0
/Users/user1/Documents/Projects/MyProject/iOS/MyProject_iOS/proj1/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:QgI-8L-Hco: warning: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width before iOS 8.0
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
/Users/user1/Documents/Projects/MyProject/iOS/MyProject_iOS/proj1/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: Exception while running ibtool: Could not find class named UIImage
```

I have tried cleaning and deleting the derived data folder and rebuilding but still the same error. I am running on Xcode 9.1.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix ibtool failed with Main.storyboard error: shouldBeArchived unrecognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858083/how-to-fix-ibtool-failed-with-main-storyboard-error-shouldbearchived-unrecogniz)

Answer (score 0):

import uikit into header file of your view controller.

like in viewcontroller.h

add below line
`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h`>

i think this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I have checked all .h files. They have #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> but I still cannot compile. Please help.

Comment: compile other projects if they run then make new project for this. may be this is issue of linking error. if other projects is also throws the same error then re-install your xcode.